# What event listener is used to validate checkout fields

Tags: magento2, checkout

I can see that the input fields are validated on `keyup`.

I want to simulate `keyup` on a field when clicking a button, so that the field gets validated.

I tried doing it with JQ:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
            e.which = 13;
            e.keyCode = 13;
            $('input[name="street[0]"]').trigger(e)
```

But no luck, which probably means that Magento 2 is not listening for JQ events.

How do I make Magento think I typed in a field? (Or just validate a field, if there's a way to do it better)